# bridge or NAT to connect two routers?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, connection, nat, bridge

I need to connect my ISP WAN router to my personal router. I need to access my networking services such as HTTP,FTP from the internet. My question is, what should I do in this case? Should I bridge the two routers on Ethernet , or to NAT a physical port from ISP router to my home router? And most importantly, how can I do it? I have some basic networking knowledge, I'll be able to understand if I'll get some hints.

Comment: You should bridge the ISP router and port forward on your router. Your router WAN port should have a public IP address if the ISP router is bridged.

Comment: Just did it, and it works as expected. Thanks! Why did you comment it instead of answering the question? I could have marked as Answered, hence you would have got the "credit". Thank you very much.